# IE8 Gradient doesn't show up

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm fixing my template for Internet Explorer 8, and now I have a question. Why doesn't a gradient appear on an element with CSS: `display: table;`?

Is there any solution for this?

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5d6372', endColorstr='#8d929e',GradientType=0 );
```

Comment: Answering to your comment in my question (I removed it because it doesn't answer your question now) "You think that I don't know it? I'm using IE-specific gradient, which doesn't appear when I'm trying to add CSS: display: table;" => "Relax, remember your original tags, thanks to some other user who re-tagged your question, now we know you're using IE-specific gradients (you edited your question too). Your original tags included "html5" and "css3". If you knew that, why this tags?"

Comment: Now I feel like stupid kid, 'HTML5' and 'CSS3' because I'm trying to create gradient, in every browser except IE it's working.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer: Many, many, many people on SO mindlessly tag their questions [html5][css3] even though they're unrelated for reasons I can't comprehend. There's not much I can do besides removing the tags manually :(

Comment: @BoltClock Hey!! Have you misunderstood my words? I was saying you did a good job re-tagging it as it wasn't a HTML5 and/or CSS3 question, but webking thought its original question was enough to let us know the problem was with IE behaviors...

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer: I know. I mean that it's unfortunate that we give others the wrong answers because they don't tag their questions properly.

Comment: It's my fault, one thing I can with this do is promise that next time I will assign proper tags.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah ok ok :) Well, after all programmers are humans, aren't they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startcolorstr` and `endcolorstr` need 8 hex digits; you have only 6.

Edit: no wait, that can't be it. Your original style does work with IE8 like that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>IE8 Gradient test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="display:table; width:100%; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5d6372', endColorstr='#8d929e', GradientType=0 );">
   <div style="display:table-row"><div style="display:table-cell">test</div></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

So can you show what you tried?

Comment: You've got a background in there, that overrides the filter. Remove the `background: #5d6372;` and it will work. (You can leave the other, gradient, backgrounds in.)

Comment: Thanks! It's working, but I have another question, why when I remove `display: table;` it's working too?

Comment: Hm, that's interesting; I hadn't noticed. I don't know! But it's best not to think about problems with IE once you have them solved. It caused headaches.